# Python: At most X awaitable operations in parallel

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a lot of tasks that I would like to do in parallel using async calls, but I don't want to do more than X at a time to not OOM. Is there some support in Python for that to achieve easily (not too much complexity). What I have currently is:

```
sample_size = self.targets/ TEST_SAMPLE_RATIO
targets = sample(self.targets, sample_size)
for batch in grouper(targets, TEST_BATCH_SIZE):
   results_await = [self.slowAsyncProcessing(target) for target in batch]
   results = await gather(*results_await)
   for result in results:
     fastNonAsyncProcessingOfTheResult(result)
```

The problem with this is that in every batch I will have to wait for the slowest target and not add more work that could be done at that time (ideally, eventually all slow-pokes would be executed in parallel - right now they will be executed serially).

Is there some support for executing things in parallel with a max batch size? Or maybe there are some well supported libraries that do that?

Comment: What function exactly do you want to call at most `x` times concurrently?

Comment: `self.slowAsyncProcessing(target)` is the expensive, slow function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`asyncio.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) to limit how many times the `slowAsyncProcessing` function runs concurrently.

```py
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

async def slowAsyncProcessing(target):
    async with sem:
        ...
```